# Composite Index not indexing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm having a strange problem with several composite indexes I have created. Basically they are not indexing old and new entries if they have a specific field.

[FYI, I inserted all my entities as they come so the built-in indexes are default as the docs says]

The field is a date, actually it's a string, called endDate.

[image: HealthKit structure]

And the indexes are (one which does not have the endDate field works, the others do not):

[image]

And problems arises when I make a GQL query or one from NodeJS:

[image]

Any ideas or thoughts? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index definitions (and your query) use 'endData' but your field name is 'endDate'.  It looks like you need to change your index definition to use endDate instead of endData.

Comment: Well this was very awkward, but now it came to me that GCP do not check if a field is valid (if it exist)... Is this because since it's NoSQL I can add a completely different object to the Kind with that field in the future? just wondering....

Comment: Correct, the schema validation is entirely done within your code.